# onChange event is not triggered for checkbox in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've a checkbox with ng-click in angularJs.

Below is angularjs code -

```
var formApp = angular.module('formApp', [])
.controller('formController', function($scope) {
  $scope.onClick = function() {
    alert($scope.test.value);
    console.log('checkbox changed ')
  };
});
```

Below is the html code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
<script src="http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.9.0.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>

<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">

  <div>
    <!-- CUSTOM VALUE CHECKBOXES -->
    <label>Personal Question</label>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="awesome" 
               ng-model="formData.awesome" 
               ng-true-value="ofCourse" 
               ng-false-value="iWish" 
               ng-click="onClick"> Are you awesome?
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

But when I click the checkbox the event is not triggered.
The code is [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/PcxWQ5Cot04WmsJ3n3Py?p=preview)

Any idea why the code is not working?

Comment: you should be binding to change and not click for a checkbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing `()` : `ng-click="onClick()"`

Answer (score 1):

Change your mark up to be `onClick()` instead of `onClick`

```
<body ng-app="formApp" ng-controller="formController">


  <div>
   <!-- CUSTOM VALUE CHECKBOXES -->
        <label>Personal Question</label>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" name="awesome" ng-model="formData.awesome" ng-true-value="ofCourse" ng-false-value="iWish"

                ng-click="onClick()">
                Are you awesome?
            </label>
        </div>
      </div>

</body>
```

What you are trying to alert isn't valid. Change your js to :

```
  $scope.onClick = function() {
    console.log('checkbox changed ')
  };
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/k2iRaYexQYQdjPGHIQon